# Print all combinations from 0000 to 9999 in C#

Tags: c#, printing

just wondering if anyone had an algorithm lying around that printed all possible combos from 0000 to 9999 (trying to crack code into old phone and new to learning C#)...Million thanks. Bela

Comment: looks like homework...

Comment: No - just trying to crack code into my old phone actually

Comment: When you think about it, an algorithm which does *anything* for all possible combos from 0000 to 9999 is called **counting**. Welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: As pavium said, all the possible combos is simply counting from 0001 to 9999.  There's no need for combinatorics.

Comment: Can you edit your question to indicate the new reason?  I will take away my down-vote.

Answer (score 25):

Why complicate matters?

```
for (Int32 index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
    Console.Out.WriteLine(index.ToString("0000"));
```

Since you're commenting that you're outputting to a label, with linefeeds between each value, here's a better way:

```
List<String> values = new List<String>();
for (Int32 index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
    values.Add(index.ToString("0000"));
label1.Text = String.Join(
    Environment.NewLine,
    values.ToArray());
```

Try that and see if it gives you what you want.

Comment: Thanks! But for some reason this is going into an infinite loop (I think, cause the program just freezes)

Comment: Not with the code I posted, so you must've made an error when you wrote it down into your own program. Please post the code that freezes in your question.

Comment: @Lasse: what is wrong with Console.WriteLine? (same thing only shorter)

Comment: It's just what I have in my code standard. I use the system types, not the C# reserved words, since that goes hand in hand with methods (GetInt32) in various runtime classes, and I always write .In. or .Out. on the Console class.

Comment: We haven't learnt about Console.WriteLine, I'm just outputting to a label, sorry guys, think I'm way to basic for you...

Comment: This is the code:
 for (int index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
            {
                label1.Text+= index.ToString("0000")+"\n";
                
            }

Comment: I doubt it freezes, but it might take some time, since manipulating a string like that build 10000 temporary string. I'll post a better way.

Answer (score 10):

[WTF entry](http://thedailywtf.com/):

```
Console.WriteLine("0000"); 
Console.WriteLine("0001"); 
Console.WriteLine("0002"); 
Console.WriteLine("0003"); 

// snip everything in the middle

Console.WriteLine("9998"); 
Console.WriteLine("9999");
```

For those of you who are lacking of humor, don't try this at home.

Comment: That's actually incorrect, she has indicated it should be 4 digit aligned.

Comment: Fix the thing so that it is 4 digit aligned.

Comment: An answer worthy of question.

Comment: Note that for a complete WTF answer you should actually post all those lines here (you'll get a scrollbar for the code field), but then leave out a random line, just for kicks.

Comment: I can prompt how to make this task easier. Try this:
Console.Write(@"0000
0001
0002
0003
....
9998
9999
");

Comment: Oh, my God, I forget about "\n"

Comment: The Real WTF answer would be to have the for loop contain a (switch i) { case 0: Console.WriteLine("0000"); case 1: Console.WriteLine("0001"); /* etc */ } (ref: http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The_FOR-CASE_paradigm.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Do you want to count to 9999?

Comment: I wanna get all possible combos

Comment: and how is that different from counting?

Answer (score 2):

I think Digitalex's solution is the most elegant but too memory-consuming.

Here's a better option:

```
foreach (var number in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000).Select(i => i.ToString("0000")))
    Console.WriteLine(number);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int index = 0; index < 10000; index++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Like Lasse said, simply print them in sequence. But you can do even simpler with Linq;

```
Enumerable.Range(0, 9999).ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
```

You could avoid the "ToList" as well, if you had a helper function (which I normally would have in a Utilities class);

```
public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements, Action<T> action)
{
    foreach (var element in elements) { action(element); }
}
```

Note that this utility method is not strictly required for it to work, but would greatly diminish the memory requirements (since ToList actcually creates a list of all the numbers in memory).

Comment: So you are that guy, the guy that shoots moskitos with missile launchers and AK47... I didn't know.

Comment: I downvoted you for suggesting a 'ForEach' extension, which is completely useless. The 'foreach' keyword is good enough, and this extension would only be confusing.

Comment: I see your point, but it's a matter of personal opinion I think. Personally, I prefer one-liners for simple things like these.

Comment: Also you are not keeping starting zeroes in your solution.

Comment: Good point, would be like others here have pointed out; in my example would be ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine("{0:0000}", x))

Comment: Eamon; or like the util-function I wrote. I find this handy for a lot of scenarios, and always put it in some Utilities class in my projects.

Comment: `Enumerable.Range(0,9999)` does not include the number 9999

Comment: Eamon: indeed, you're right. I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to correct this... :)